# Performance based on searching a integer or a long string (unique) in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance

I have 5 columns in a table in database and two are unique (one is integer and another is a string).

integer are like
`1,5,6,7,9,0` and
string are like   `http://exmaple.com/Book-on-the-self-no-2`.

Now which column should be used for searching rows??? how will it impact the performance?
database is sql or mysql?

Thank..

Comment: This question is not well formulated. What is the criteria you wish to search on, and even more important, which columns are indexed? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Dear Abhishek, Performance optimization is a vast field in itself. You have to consider multiple parameters - Have a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the less comparisons and manipulation of data *(like reading from disk)* MySQL has to make, the faster it'll go.

Which means that searching on integers *(a couple of bytes)* will generally be faster than searching on *(possibly long)* strings.

In your case, as a sidenote : don't forget adding an index on the field your searching on -- depending on the kind of query you're doing, it'll speed up things a lot.

Comment: i have done index on string long column which consist url. i am trying to make hard coded url and store it in database for per row. Is it nice idea??

Comment: i mean i have done index on the column in which i am storing the urls.